# Замена столбцов в MySQL с CHAR на VARCHAR если присутствует хотя бы один типа VARCHAR

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Читал в мануале что все столбцы типа `CHAR` изменяются автоматически на `VARCHAR`, если в таблице присутствует хотя бы один столбец с типом `VARCHAR`, это актуально для последних версий MySQL?

В PhpMyAdmin никаких изменений не произошло, хотя есть `VARCHAR` среди `CHAR`.
Версия: `5.5.40-MariaDB`

Comment: *Читал в мануале* — приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку на это «руководство».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/silent-column-changes.html `второй маркер списка`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Читал в [мануале](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/silent-column-changes.html) что все столбцы типа CHAR изменяются автоматически на VARCHAR, если в таблице присутствует хотя бы один столбец с типом VARCHAR.

всё-таки лучше читать актуальную документацию, а не перевод древних версий:

> [Before MySQL 5.0.3, if any column in a table has a variable length, the entire row becomes variable-length as a result. Therefore, if a table contains any variable-length columns (VARCHAR, TEXT, or BLOB), all CHAR columns longer than three characters are changed to VARCHAR columns.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/silent-column-changes.html)

мой вольный перевод:

> до версии *mysql 5.0.3*, если любой столбец в таблице имел переменную длину, вся строка становилась в результате переменной длины. поэтому, если таблица содержала столбец переменной длины (*varchar*, *text* или *blob*), все столбцы типа *char* длинее трёх символов изменялись на тип *varchar*.